# Compile OpenCV with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, compilation, symlink

Try compile. Get error. What his need?

[ 62%] Linking CXX shared library ....\bin\libopencv_superres310d.dll
Info: resolving vtable for cv::ParallelLoopBody by linking to __imp___ZTVN2cv16P
arallelLoopBodyE (auto-import)
Info: resolving vtable for cv::VideoCapture by linking to __imp___ZTVN2cv12Video
CaptureE (auto-import)
Creating library file: ....\lib\libopencv_superres310d.dll.a
c:/qt/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.e
xe: warning: auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import spec
ified on the command line.
This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols
 from auto-imported DLLs.
Cannot export _ZN2cv3Mat3ptrIN12_GLOBAL__N_18_Point4fEEEPT_i: symbol not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_superres310d.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/superres/CMakeFiles/opencv_superres.dir/all] Error
 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: As I understand, I need compile with flag --enable-auto-import, but where his indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first problem is your function with computer when you use opencv3. 1, opencv3. 1 Newest operating systems are supported: Windows 10 and OSX 10.11 (Visual Studio 2015 and XCode 7.1.1), the function can't use old computer try with old version opencv

Comment: is not problem of qt or mingw32-make

Comment: which version of opencv supports win7?

Comment: version 2.4 of opencv